# Thumbnails, channel_short_name and channel fields

Tags: thumbnails

I have a image "thumbnail" field in multiple channels, ie:
"news_thumbnail"
"projects_thumbnail"
"editorials_thumbnail"

With these images, I use EE's resizing feature to crop multiple sizes of the image.

I'm attempting to display the images using the following:

```
{{channel_short_code}_thumbnail}{path}_frontpage/{filename}.{extension}{/{channel_short_code_thumbnail}
```

This outputs to

```
{news_thumbnail}{path}_frontpage/{filename}.{extension}{/{news_thumbnail}
```

The {path} {filename} and {extension} variables aren't being processed properly.

However if I hardcode the channel field and use:

```
{news_thumbnail}{path}_frontpage/{filename}.{extension}{/{news_thumbnail}
```

{path},{filename} and {extension} are parsed to their proper values, and the image is displayed properly.

Any idea how to get this working properly?

Comment: Just to clarify - you mean (and are using) `{channel_short_name}`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the value of one variable (i.e., `{channel_short_name}`) to determine the key of another variable located at the *same level of processing* (i.e., `{news_thumbnail}`), which won't work.

I'd suggest using [preload_replace](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/preload_replacement.html) variables instead, since they are parsed before any module tags are processed:

```
{preload_replace:current_channel="news"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="{current_channel}"}
    {{current_channel}_thumbnail}{path}_frontpage/{filename}.{extension}{/{current_channel}_thumbnail}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```